# Change cell size to a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to change the size of the cells of a WPF System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid?

Say, I want all my cells be of size (100 x 50).

Answer (score 4):

```
<DataGrid ...
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    <!--you can set Name and ItemsSource to other values, this is just a sample-->
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the ColumnWidth and RowHeight?

```
 <DataGrid ColumnWidth="100" RowHeight="50"/>
```

More info on styling the DataGrid can be found at 
[Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx.).